# Vue.js - How do I execute a function once the API has been fetched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a Fetch API function which is getting data from a server. I then want to execute another function called `updateLocal` after it is being fetched.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchAPI();
  updateLocal();
}, []);
```

I want the fetchAPI to be done first then updateLocal() after the API has successfully loaded.

This is the fetchAPI code:

```
  const fetchAPI = async () => {
    const fetched = await fetch(url);
    const modifiedData = await fetched.json();
    setData(modifiedData);
    console.log(data);

    //setQuestions(modifiedData);
    //console.log(modifiedData);

    //updateLocal();
  };
```

I have looked everywhere and have been stuck for so long.

Comment: await fetchAPI()

Comment: You can't just use async-await inside `useEffect()` without some ugly IFEE wrapper. That's why in this case I'd prefer `fetchAPI().then(() => updateLocal())`

Answer (score 1):

async functions return promise, so

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchAPI().then(updateLocal);
}, []);

const fetchAPI = async () => {
  const fetched = await fetch(url);
  const modifiedData = await fetched.json();
  setData(modifiedData);
  setTimeout(3000, () => console.log(modifiedData)); // delaying the console.log call without pausing the flow
  return modifiedData; // so this return will be executed BEFORE console.log
};
```

Comment: If I put a timeout inside the fetchAPI function the updateLocal function still occurs before the timeout is finished

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function callFetchAPIAndThenupdateLocal() {
    await fetchAPI();
    await updateLocal();
  }
  callFetchAPIAndThenupdateLocal();
}, []);
```

Comment: Should work, but probably no need to await `updateLocal()`

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case it might not be required